# Get select value when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to detect the value and do some stuff (not important for the question). I am unable to get the value when the page is ready, but when selecting a value, it can find the value. How can I pass `this` to the function?

### HTML

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="choise1">choise1</option>
    <option value="choise2">choise2</option>
    <option value="choise3" selected="selected">choise3</option>
    <option value="choise4">choise4</option>
</select>
```

### Javascript

```
function check_select() {
    alert( "!" + $( this ).val() + "!" );
}

$('#select').on( 'change', check_select );

// Why is value not set?
$('#select').ready( check_select );
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7en4op4j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` elements do not raise a `ready` event. To do what you require you would need to just call the `check_select()` function in the `document.ready` handler itself. You would also need to change the scope of `this` within the function due to the logic in the function. To do that you can use `$.proxy()`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#select').on('change', check_select); // on change
    $.proxy(check_select, $('#select'))(); // on load
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7en4op4j/6/)

Comment: Never knew about `.proxy()`. Loving it

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is set to `onDomReady`, if you change this to `No wrap, in head` then you can take advantage of jQuery's handling of dom ready.

Thereafter, what you want to do is call your method with the context of `this` set to the select element in question:

```
check_select.call($('#select')[0])
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7en4op4j/2/

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a bit. Used `$(document).ready()` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/7en4op4j/5/

```
function check_select(obj) {
    alert( "!" + $( obj ).val() + "!" );
}

$('#select').on( 'change',  function(){
    check_select($(this));
                 } );

// Why is value not set?
$(document).ready( function(){
    check_select($("#select")) 
});
```

Comment: If you're passing a jQuery object to the function there is no need to wrap it again in `$()` within that function!

Answer (score 0):

On load of the function your trying to read the value with 'this' which is the object of the document. instead of using 'this' select id.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7en4op4j/1/

```
function check_select() {
alert( "!" + $( '#select' ).val() + "!" );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

there is not ready event for dom elements, at least i have never used it in that way.
You can use `$(document).on('ready',callback)` to execute somethin(code) when the all the DOM is ready. That is why it does not work correct.

instead of this just use `$(document).on('ready',function)` , and keep the **check_select** function for the change event.

```
function check_select() {
    alert( "!" + $( this ).val() + "!" );
}

$('#select').on( 'change', check_select );

$(document).on('ready',function(){  
  alert($('select').val());
})
```

live jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/7en4op4j/7/

hope helps,good luck